# component router not working with ng-bootstrap

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular2-routing, ng-bootstrap

I am writing below code to navigate between tabs and

```
<ngb-tabset>
  <ngb-tab title="Add">
    <template ngbTabContent routerLink="/retail/retail-add">

    </template>
  </ngb-tab>
 <ngb-tab title="Collection">
    <template ngbTabContent routerLink="/retail/retail-collection">

      </template>
  </ngb-tab>
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</ngb-tabset>
```

It is showing tabs , But on click of tab neither It is routing to that component nor giving any error on console.
Please help

Answer (score 4):

To solve the issue that only clicks on the title cause a content change, you could make use of the [`tabChange` event](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tabs#NgbTabChangeEvent):

**component.html**

```
<ngb-tabset (tabChange)="onTabChange($event)">
  <ngb-tab [id]="first" [title]="First">
    <ng-template ngbTabContent></ng-template>
  </ngb-tab>
  <ngb-tab [id]="second" [title]="Second">
    <ng-template ngbTabContent></ng-template>
  </ngb-tab>
</ngb-tabset>
```

**component.ts**

```
onTabChange($event: NgbTabChangeEvent) {
  if ($event.nextId === 'first') {
    this.router.navigateByUrl(__your_first_url__);
  } else if ($event.nextId === 'second') {
    this.router.navigateByUrl(__your_second_url__);
  }
}
```

As all solutions discussed so far do not really look like best practices, I opened an [issue on GitHub that was added as a feature request](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/1632).

Comment: Slightly late - alternatively make the <a> inside the <ng-template> take up all the room of its parent; by moving the padding from the parent to the <a> tag.

Answer (score 2):

The `template` tag has been deprecated. It's now `ng-template`:

```
<ngb-tab>
   <ng-template ngbTabTitle>
     <a routerLink="/retail/retail-add">Add</a>
   </ng-template>
   <ng-template ngbTabContent>

   </ng-template>
</ngb-tab>
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using `nav tabs` - I know it doesnt fully address the question but it is a viable clean alternative. In fact, for example, the demo bootstrap website uses these for tab navigation and `href`. see https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navs/#tabs

We can embed `routerLinks` instead of having to use click listeners. We can use `routerLinkActive` or an `ngClass` for active tab

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive [routerLink]=['path', 'to', 'component']>Tab1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive [routerLink]=['path', 'to', 'component']>Tab2</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div> 
  //Should load each tabs component from the routerLink here
  <router-outlet></router-outlet> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
<ngb-tab title="Add">
   <template ngbTabContent routerLink="/retail/retail-add">

   </template>
</ngb-tab>
```

With:

```
<ngb-tab>
   <template ngbTabTitle>
     <a routerLink="/retail/retail-add">Add</a>
   </template>
   <template ngbTabContent>

   </template>
</ngb-tab>
```

Finally, move **Router Outlet** on app component and enjoy ;).

Comment: Tried this approach (with _ng-template_ instead of _template_). Problem is, tab content switching works when I click on the tab title text only.
When I click on any tab, but not on title text, tab is displayed as switched, but routing doesn't happen and the content remains that of old tab.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who come looking for solution for how to make routing works with ng-bootstrap tabs. I have made an example app to demonstrate that. I used secondary router outlet for to render tab component.

See the demo here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-bootstrap-routable-tabs

And code here:
https://github.com/kashpatel/ng-bootstrap-routable-tabs

Answer (score 0):

Incase you are using ng-template for routerlink like below :

```
<ngb-tabset #tabset="ngbTabset">
<ngb-tab id="tab1">
<ng-template ngbTabTitle>
<a class="btn-link" [routerLink]="['./nestedRoute1']">Tab1</a>
</ng-template>
</ngb-tab>
<ngb-tab id="tab2">
<ng-template ngbTabTitle>
<a class="btn-link" [routerLink]="['./nestedRoute2']">Tab2</a>
</ng-template>
</ngb-tab>
</ngb-tabset>
```

And facing problem like routing only happens if the title is clicked (not the tab), try removing padding for the outer anchor tag and make the inner anchor tag i.e btn-link in the above code as inline-block and provide padding to it.

Thus any click on the tab will correspond to inner anchor tag with router link.